# Repeat XMLHttpRequest request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

My app have some jquery http calls and some angular http calls....

So.. to add a param to every request, I add this code at the beginning of my code.

```
var op = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {

    this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {

        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200 ){
            // http call is done
        }

    }, false);
    arguments[1] = arguments[1]+'?test=testParam';
    var resp = op.apply(this, arguments);
    return resp;
};
```

Now I want 2 things

1) I want to change the response before apply it

2) If the response is 404.... I want to make another call.... take the response... and then repeat the call with some new params

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that we can't extend `XMLHttpRequest` to retry the connection because we can't fire `.open` if we have the `.onload` event fired. Writing several `.open` of the same `XMLHttpRequest` instance causes that each `.open` rewrites the previously `.open`, but once `.onload` event is fired, we can't reuse that instance (the request doesn't send), so we have to create another instance of `XMLHttpRequest`. So the closest approach in my opinion is reusing the code, like this:

```js
var param = 106;

var div = document.getElementById("retry");
var div2 = document.getElementById("success");
var div3 = document.getElementById("response");
div.innerHTML = "Trying: " + param;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + param);
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status === 200) { //<-- we use this instead of xhr
    div2.innerHTML = "Success: " + param;
    div3.innerHTML = this.responseText;
  } else {
    var newXhr = xhr; //<-- we have to create another instance
    newXhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + param);
    newXhr.onload = xhr.onload; //<--we reuse the function
    newXhr.send();
    div.innerHTML = "Trying: " + param;
    param--;
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

```html
<div id="retry">
</div>
<div id="success">
</div>
<div id="response">
</div>
```

This is another approach (my previous answer), that I think is better:

```js
function myAjax(param) {
  var div = document.getElementById("retry");
  var div2 = document.getElementById("success");
  var div3 = document.getElementById("response");
  div.innerHTML = "Trying: " + param;
  console.log(param);


  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + param);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      div2.innerHTML = "Success: " + param;
      div3.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    } else {
      param--;
      myAjax(param); //I'm calling again the function
    }
  };

  xhr.send();
}

myAjax(105);
```

```html
<div id="retry">

</div>
<div id="success">
</div>
<div id="response">
</div>
```

Comment: This is out of subject..... I'm trying to make an interceptor, not recursive calls

Comment: @Michalis I've updated the answer to fit more in your question.